# Set sudo password differently from login one

Tags: sudo

As a privileged user I am trying to set the `sudo` password to another then the one used at login.

I have done some research but have not found an answer. Does `sudo` support that kind of configuration?

If you ever lose your password, you lose everything. Someone could log in and promote himself to `root` with the same password.

`sudo` has an option to ask for `root` password instead of invoked user password, (`rootpw`), but sharing `root` password is definitely not an option, that is why we set up `sudo`.

I did `config 2FA` in the past, it worked great, but also defeats the automation purpose. For example if you want to execute a privileged command across a dozen of servers with an `expect` script, adding `2FA` doesn't allow you to do that.

The closest solution I have found is to only allow SSH private key and setup pass-phrase with a key which differs from the `sudo` (login) password. Still, it is not comfy, because in an emergency situation you can't login with a PC where it doesn't have that key.

Comment: Why do you need this exactly? Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Wouldn't be better to have dual-factor authentication for logging into system with a privileged account and then have 'NOPASSWD', so that sudo does not ask for password? Then you should have of course a separate emergency local account with strong password to be able to login when network is down (no ssh access).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to ask for the root password, as opposed to the user's password, there are options that you can put in `/etc/sudoers`. `rootpw` in particular will make it ask for the root password. There is `runaspw` and `targetpw` as well; see the sudoers(5) manpage for details.

Other than that, sudo does its authentication (like everything else) through PAM. PAM supports per-application configuration. Sudo's config is in (at least on my Debian system) `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, and looks like this:

```
$ cat sudo 
#%PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

In other words, by default, it authenticates like everything else on the system. You can change that `@include common-auth` line, and have PAM (and thus sudo) use an alternate password source. The non-commented-out lines in common-auth look something like (by default, this will be different if you're using e.g., LDAP):

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

You could use e.g., `pam_userdb.so` instead of `pam_unix.so`, and store your alternate passwords in a Berkeley DB database.

### example

I created the directory `/var/local/sudopass`, owner/group `root:shadow`, mode `2750`. Inside it, I went ahead and created a password database file using `db5.1_load` (which is the version of Berkeley DB in use on Debian Wheezy):

```
# umask 0027
# db5.1_load -h /var/local/sudopass -t hash -T passwd.db
anthony
WMaEFvCFEFplI
^D
```

That hash was generated with `mkpasswd -m des`, using the password "password". Very highly secure! (Unfortunately,  pam_userdb seems to not support anything better than the ancient `crypt(3)` hashing).

Now, edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and remove the `@include common-auth` line, and instead put this in place:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_userdb.so crypt=crypt db=/var/local/sudopass/passwd
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

Note that pam_userdb adds a `.db` extension to the passed database, so you must leave the `.db` off.

According to [dannysauer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/48650/dannysauer) in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one/94646?noredirect=1#comment143868_94646), you may need to make the same edit to `/etc/pam.d/sudo-i` as well.

Now, to sudo, I must use `password` instead of my real login password:

```
anthony@sudotest:~$ sudo -K
anthony@sudotest:~$ sudo echo -e '\nit worked'
[sudo] password for anthony: passwordRETURN

it worked
```

Comment: Make sure to also configure "sudo-i", which newer versions of sudo often use for "sudo -i" (if the vendor hasn't changed something).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the PAM config pls?

Comment: @ShâuShắc I've added an example, including PAM config changes.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont find db51-utils anywhere in Redhat/centos or sources, is it only available in Debian variants?

Comment: @ShâuShắc I believe RHEL, Fedora, and CentOS call it `libdb-utils`. The command name may be a little different, too (maybe it won't have a version, or will be a different version—but it'll match `db.*_load`)

Comment: My system is redhat. This is original file:

$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include      system-auth
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session    required     pam_limits.so

Comment: And after I made the edit:

$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo
#%PAM-1.0
# auth       include      system-auth


auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_userdb.so crypt=crypt db=/usr/local/etc/sudopass/passwd
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so


account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth

session    optional     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session    required     pam_limits.so

Comment: I have tried the new password, but it keeps telling me the password is incorrect

Comment: @ShâuShắc it looks like you didn't remove the include line. So it's trying to match both passwords. RedHat appears to use a slightly different PAM setup than Debian.

Comment: Hi derobert,if you check it closely, I commented the line: # auth include system-auth. Also sorry for the very confusing format, it looks like to me comment on stackexchange doesnt accept formatting

Comment: @ShâuShắc there is a debug option, add that to the pam_userdb line, and check your authentication logs... Maybe that'll explain what is going wrong.

Comment: @ShâuShắc I created a CentOS 6.4 VM and tested this on it, it works for me... Did you change the username in the password file to your username (instead of "anthony")?

Comment: Of course I changed it to my username. Later, I actually configured it successfully, with the help of google. Its slightly different from yours, though. I will share it tomorrow because Im on mobile atm. Now I need to work out a way that other users running sudo with normal authen method, and this configuration is applicable to me only, because Im the only person in this organisation really care about tight security. If it can be applied per user or group, that'd be perfect solution

Comment: Some distributions (Arch, the Red Hat distros) do not provide the `mkpasswd` utility mentioned here. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev seems like that'd make a good question for the site. Search first to make sure it hasn't already been asked.

Comment: The "the ancient `crypt(3)` hashing" on modern versions of glibc has support for sha-512, eg. `mkpasswd -m sha-512`. pam_userdb.so can handle these just fine.

Comment: This answer is extremely useful; thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem (on Ubuntu 18.04)  with authentication failure. Is this still active enough to get help?

Comment: @RhythmInk probably you should ask your own question, feel free to link to this one. That way you have the full question to provide details (as opposed to the limited length & formatting of comments) and also it'll be presented to a much wider audience. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 6):

For Redhat/Centos, the requirement can be achieved with following steps:

Create custom user and pass:

```
# db_load -t hash -T /usr/local/etc/passwd.db
user
pass
^d
```

Edit the sudo pam.d file so that it looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sudo

auth            required        pam_userdb.so db=/usr/local/etc/passwd
account         required        pam_userdb.so db=/usr/local/etc/passwd
password        include         system-auth

session         optional        pam_keyinit.so revoke
session         required        pam_limits.so
```

Im still looking for the way to config, so that only a certain user/group must be authen by this custom method, others still can be authen by the normal system-auth method. Can anyone give me some advises?

Comment: You should be able to do this with the full action syntax in PAM. e.g., `[user_unknown=ignore,success=ok,default=bad]`... but you'll have to play with that (and read the PAM docs) to get it right

Comment: This could also be accomplished using `pam_succeed_if` to skip one module if the user is in one of a list of groups, or to skip two modules if not.

Comment: So, something generally like this: /// auth      [success=ignore default=1]  pam_succeed_if.so user in danny:frank ///
auth sufficient danny_frank_module.so ///
auth sufficient not_danny_frank.so

Answer (score 3):

I don't think sudo supports such a setup. The purpose of the sudo password prompt is to ensure that the person issuing the sudo command is the same person that is logged in, and the easiest way to do that is to ask for the currently logged in user to re-authenticate themselves.

In other words, the purpose of the sudo password prompt is *not* to establish *authority*, it is to establish *identity*. Based on the established identity and the sudo configuration, a decision can be made whether the user in question has the necessary authority or access rights.

Comment: Sudo doesn't (except in the case that you want to ask the root password, or a particular user, or the target user's password), but PAM does. And sudo uses PAM.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is that your account password can be disclosed.  The solution is to not use the login password in a way that it can be disclosed.  With ssh, the password is encrypted on the wire, so it's fine.  People turn off password auth with ssh to prevent password guessing attacks, not to protect password confidentiality.  If you're using the same account password for anything else, make sure that you're using a secure, encrypted channel to provide the password.  If you're worried about a keylogger or whatever, stop using untrusted machines to log in.

If someone can get your ssh password, they can probably also get the alternate sudo password, so you're better off investing time into making your connections more secure than spending time just making things more complicated just for the illusion of more security.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have immediate access to a system where I can test this
and work out the details, but I have an idea:

- (Assume your normal login account is `shau`.)
- Create a second account: `shau2`. 
  (I’m not sure whether you want it to have the same UID as `shau`.)
- Configure `shau2` to have sudo privileges with NOPASSWD.
- Set up an alias or a shell script to do `su shau2 -c sudo "$@"`. 
  This should ask for `shau2`’s password. 
  If that is entered correctly, it will run `sudo` as `shau2`
  (which should not ask for a password).
- Remove `shau`’s sudo privileges.

Unfortunately, you would have to repeat this for every user who has sudo privileges.

Answer (score 1):

My solution isn't any different then the excellently proposed ones.

However, I do include ALL commands for all steps taking out any guesswork or further reading.

I'm not against reading, just there are time when a pure reference is required. I hope others would find this useful.

I've tested this on Ubnutu 22.04.

I've installed `db-util` and `whois` (for `mkpasswd`):

```bash
sudo apt --yes install db_util whois
```

```bash
# Run this from your user
# Plaintext password
# Flavor is either sudo or sudo-i, recommended to test only on one first
PASSWD='password'; FLAVOR="sudo-i"

# Uncomment next line to erase existing db and start from scratch:
# sudo bash -c "[[ ! -r /var/local/sudopass/passwd.db ]] || rm /var/local/sudopass/passwd.db;"

[[ -d /var/local/sudopass ]] \
|| sudo install --owner root --group shadow --mod 2750 --directory \
&& sudo sed -E 's|^@include[ \t]+common-auth$|# @include\tcommon-auth\n\nauth\t[success=1 default=ignore]\tpam_userdb.so crypt=crypt db=/var/local/sudopass/passwd\nauth\trequisite\t\t\tpam_deny.so\nauth\trequired\t\t\tpam_permit.so\n|' -i "/etc/pam.d/$FLAVOR" \
&& printf "%s\n" "$USER" "$( mkpasswd -m sha-512 "$PASSWD" )" \
| sudo bash -c "
umask 0027;
db_load -Tt hash -h /var/local/sudopass passwd.db
" && printf "\n\n" \
&& sudo -k ${FLAVOR#sudo} || sudo journalctl -xe

unset PASSWD
```

Here is what's going on:

- `PASSWD='password'; FLAVOR="sudo-i"`:
  Assignment of plaintext to PASSWD
  Choice of FLAVOR (sudo, sudo-i) - I recommend you start with `sudo-i`
  so that `sudo` continues to behave the same until you've made sure
  everything is working correctly.
- `[[ ! -r ....`:
  If not DB readbale (for sudo), continue, otherwise, remove the file.
  It is written this way, so that it 'always succeeds'
- `[[ -d ...`:
  In case the directory doesn't exists, create it with the proper permissions.
- `sudo sed ... -i ...`:
  For the specific FLAVOR, replace the default entry with the `pam_user.db` one.
- `printf "%s\n" "$USER" "$( mkpasswd -m sha-512 "$PASSWD" )"`:
  The `mkpasswd` generates a password and hashes it with SHA-512.
  Then the current user's name and the hashed password are passed to:
  `| sudo ... db_load ...` - which then loads the values into the DB.
- `sudo -k ${FLAVOR#sudo}`:
  Testing the `sudo` prompt. The notation around FLAVOR strips `sudo`
  from the begning, which means that the correct FLAVOR of the `sudo`
  command will be called for testing.
  `-k` invalidates any cached password, forcing to enter the password.
- `|| sudo journalctl -xe`:
  If something failed, display the latest system's logs.
- `unset PASSWD` - This shouldn't remain in the open.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@Shâu Shắc** for the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96253/118991)! That solution also works for **LinuxMint 17.1 Cinnamon 32bit** (I've only installed `db-util` package in order to run `db_load`).

But I am very confused with the resultant `passwd.db` file. I've did the same as in your answer (but used *david* and *jones*, they look more eye-catching):

```
# db_load -t hash -T /usr/local/etc/passwd.db
david
jones
^d
```

But entered credentials are stored inside hash file as plain text:

```
# grep 'jones.*david'  /usr/local/etc/passwd.db
Binary file /usr/local/etc/passwd.db matches
```

You can also see *david* and *jones* via **mcedit**:

[image]

Yes, it's possible to restrict permissions of `/usr/local/etc/passwd.db`. But anyway, username and password stored as plain text are bad.

---

Even with separate **sudo** password there are some potential security holes (by default distro setup). Thus, separate password is not applicable for **su** (so it is possible to start root session using `su` and login password). Also separate password is not respected by **Policy Kit** (it is possible to start **Synaptic** using `synaptic-pkexec` and login password. Then delete packages...).  These issues can be eliminated by additional tuning of configuration files.

In general seems that secure separate sudo password can be achieved only with aid of custom PAM module (perhaps, such module will compare password and SHA-512 hash read from file) or SELinux functionality.

PS: sorry, it should be a comment. But it goes as answer because of text format. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you must hash your password manually using `mkpasswd` before storing it in the database.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to install the application using the sudo user, by running the command `apt-get install`.

The `apt-get` install command will by default install the application globally.

For example:

```
sudo su - <sudo_username>
echo "your_sudo_password" | sudo -S apt-get install <package> -y
```

Comment: Welcome! This approach has already been described, in more detail, in [Scott’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94700/86440).