# Touch-friendly lock screen for Gnome

Tags: gnome, screen-lock

I installed Fedora Linux with Gnome as a desktop environment on my Microsoft Surface Go.

I want a lock-screen to be touch friendly -- something like a pattern lock, or a pin lock (with a keyboard being replaced with a numpad), or anything along those lines.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147355/297754) suggests replacing lock screen password with a simpler one, but this still means I will have to use an unwieldy on-screen keyboard (wake up screen, click on the input field to bring up keyboard, switch to number entry, key in the pincode, press enter on the on-screen-keyboard).

Is there a way to get experience similar to that of a phone or a tablet?

P.S: By default Gnome offers either fingerprint login (I don't have a sensor AFAIK), or a regular password login screen.