# What is my sudo password?

Tags: sudo, password

When installing things I am sometimes asked for my sudo password. I don't remember ever having one or setting one. But I do know my su password which has always worked fine for me. It is not the same as my sudo as it doesn't work when I try it.

How do I find out what my sudo password is?

Answer (score 5):

It is usually your personal login password. For example:

```
derek$ sudo ls /var/log/secret
[sudo] password for derek: <type derek's login password> 
audit.log  audit.log.1  audit.log.2
```

This can be altered by policy files such as /etc/sudoers. See for example [Set sudo password differently from login one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one?rq=1)

Comment: I tried my login password (lets say it is "hello") and some incorrect passwords. When I try incorrect passwords I get:Sorry, try again. When I try my login password I get:hello is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

Comment: You, user derek, may not have sudo permissions; ask your sysadmin. In your comment you gave a weird error message "hello is not in the sudoers file" I thought our hypothetical user:password was derek:hello; I would expect an error "derek is not in the sudoers file" but sudoers never contains passwords.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It did return "derek is not..." not "password is not...". Also it is my personal laptop. I guess I am the sysadmin.

Comment: @Derek That means that your user is neither in `/etc/sudoers` nor in a group that is. Common convention is to have a group called `wheel` that will have sudo access and then add users to that group.

Comment: @Kyrias in debian since at least version 5.0 (Lenny), the `sudo` group has sudo permissions by default.

Comment: Still needs to make sure his user is in the group, also that he's even using Debian.

Comment: @kyrias. I checked my /etc/sudoers file and it is completely empty. What should I see there?

Comment: @Derek, That sounds like something is off. What distro is this on?

Comment: @kyrias, Scientific Linux 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root password.

Look in file `/etc/sudoers`.
You will find a line like `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, make a note of the word after the `%`. Now add your self to this group. Logout. Login. Now sudo should work for you.

If you don't have root password, then use a live distro to do what is described above.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you have not set your root password. Try running:

```
$ sudo passwd
```

Then input your desired password.

Comment: You mean `sudo passwd`?

Comment: Also, sudo has to be configured to use the target user's password instead of the user who's running the command's password.