# Use sudo but forgotten my password

Tags: sudo, password

I am trying to use sudo on a linux server but have forgotten my password. is there any way to retrieve it?

Is this the same password I use to login to ssh?

Comment: the `sudo` password is the password you use to log.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [What is my sudo password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159357/what-is-my-sudo-password)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is my sudo password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159357/what-is-my-sudo-password)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is a utility to execute a command as another user.  So if you have superuser-privileges, then you (your current user) can run a command as e.g. the `root`-user.  Therefore you only need to use the password you also use for login.

But it might be that you do not have superuser-privileges.  This is defined in the root-only readable file `/etc/sudoers`.  There you find a line similar to

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

(although another group name could be used instead of `sudo`, e.g. `wheel`, depending on your distribution).  Any user part of this group is able to run the `sudo`-command.

If you cannot run `sudo`, you are probably not part of this group (or you just became part of the group and need to logout and then login again).