# setting sudo password different from login password

Tags: sudo, authentication, pam

I am attempting to use PAM to use a different password for sudo than I do for logging in.

I worked off of this post originally

[Set sudo password differently from login one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one)

Unfortunately, every time I do this I end up with an authentication error and I'm not sure what is going wrong. Perhaps I am hashing my password incorrectly or adding to the database incorrectly but I am unsure of what the problem is.

The configuration for sudo reads

```
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0

auth required pam_userdb.so crypt=crypt db=/var/local/sudopass/passwd.db

\#@include common-auth

@include common-account

@include common-session-noninteractive
```

I set the password using `passwd -m des password` for testing purposes and then use db5.3 to create the database passwd.db

```
db5.3_load -h /var/local/sudopass -t hash -T passwd.db
```

my_username

73o8ECeyEW3Y2 (password hash)

And then authentication error. Note, when I place this database in say my home directory, then PAM can't even find the database no matter how I set the permissions.)

## Current auth.log dump

I'm having problems getting it to give me the authentication error but here is the current problem in auth.log
`Oct 18 12:07:43 az-GlAdOS-mk11-m sudo: pam_userdb(sudo:auth): Verify user` az' with a password

Oct 18 12:07:43 az-GlAdOS-mk11-m sudo: pam_userdb(sudo:auth): user_lookup: could not open database `/var/local/sudopass/passwd.db': No such file or directory

Oct 18 12:07:43 az-GlAdOS-mk11-m sudo:       az : PAM authentication error: Error in service module ; TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/az ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/pam.d/sudo`

Comment: It would work fine. I could leave the sudo group blank and only have a root password but 

1) I don't like being logged in as root when I need to only perform one or two commands

2) Greater risk

3) I'm trying to master the use of PAM modules/authentication

Comment: What do you see in the system logs?

Comment: Last time I tried and looked it just threw an authentication error

Comment: Add a `debug` option to the `pam_userdb.so` line to get more information in the system logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide you linked to is from 5 years ago.  PAM doesn't use DES anymore.  Try using this to generate your password hash:

```
echo pass|mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `targetpw` option in `sudoers`, which would make sudo ask not for your own password, but for the password of the user you want to execute the command as (which in most cases is `root`). You can then use different passwords for your own user and the `root` user account.

Use the following snippet in your sudoers file to globally enable this behavior (edit it with `visudo`):

```
Defaults targetpw
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

The second line means that every user on the system may use sudo if they know the password of the target user. If you omit it, membership of the configured group and the target's password are both required. (Note that you can circumvent the group requirement if you have access to `su`, as it does not honor this configuration.)

You can also use one of the following two variants, which will only apply the `targetpw` directive to a specific user or group, respectively:

```
Defaults:username targetpw
username ALL=(ALL) ALL

Defaults:%groupname targetpw
%groupname ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

(Do **not** specify `ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL` if you use one of these!)